# php artisan migrate command error : could not find driver

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

My os is windows

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)

```
  at E:\Programme\Laravel Lab\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      E:\Programme\Laravel Lab\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=blog", "root", "root", [])
      E:\Programme\Laravel Lab\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need start your mysql server
then check your env configuration for your mysql, i think your password isn't root, but you put root in password.
some times password is empty. check it please.

Comment: Thanks @Abdi,
I finaly solved it.
The problem was in the php.ini (in the php folder).
I just replaced:
**;extension=pdo_mysql** to **extension=pdo_mysql**