# Laravel "php artisan migrate" gives errors

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, xampp

I'm using windows 10 with XAMPP.

When I run `php artisan migrate` I get this error:
[image]

I have looked this problem up and most say to change the php.ini file, but that has not really helped.
For example

> [Artisan migrate could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745365/artisan-migrate-could-not-find-driver?rq=1)

says to "simply uncomment the extension:

;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll" 
I can't do that though since it *simply* does not exist in my php.ini file and if I just try to add it, nothing happens.

Another

> [php artisan migrate command error : could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777992/php-artisan-migrate-command-error-could-not-find-driver)

claims that uncommenting the ";extension=pdo_mysql" to "extension=pdo_mysql" worked, but that was always uncommented for me.

Also in my database.php file i changed

[image]

to

[image]

(https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/6i0sak/i_get_errors_when_i_try_to_run_a_migration/)
but that didn't do anything either (although I didnt mess with the unix_socket thing since I dont think that applies to me).

Any ideas? This is really annoying lol.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right `php.ini` file? What folder are you looking in

Comment: Try `>php --ini` and look at the `Loaded Configuration File` line in the output to see where PHP is getting its ini file from

Comment: Haha. Turns out that I have 2 versions of php. One in my c drive and one inside XAMMP. Uncommented the pdo thing in the php.ini of the php in my c drive. Works now. Thanks!

Comment: No, thats wrong. Take the PHP on C out of your PATH and replace it with the XAMPP folder